# Deleting Directory from Pull Request Git

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, pull-request

My directory was previously called Thisfolder, but I wanted to rename it as thisfolder. I did this, but now there are both directories (Thisfolder and thisfolder) in my pull request. I can't simply delete Thisfolder from my local as there is just the "thisfolder" there.

How do I get rid of Thisfolder from my pull request?

Comment: You `git rm` all the versioned files in the corresponding folder (you can get a list with `git status` at this stage), commit and push. And next time, use `git mv` rather than a simple `mv` to avoid this kind of trouble.

Comment: Ah, I see. I wasn't in the corresponding folder. Thank you so much, it works now!